# Tomcat server could not start

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jboss

I am developing a dynamic web application on JBoss developer, but I am getting an error message:

> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at
>   \Servers\Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost-config. The Servers project
>   is closed.

Even when I try to start the server on the servers tab, it doesn't start.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to start the server outside from a terminal or command prompt to see if it is really a tomcat issue ?

Comment: @user1712095, still having problems?

Answer (score 27):

Sounds to me as if you're doing this inside Eclipse with WTP?

If so then you need to make sure that the Eclipse project called `Servers` which is created and maintained by WTP is open.

- Open the `Navigator` view
- Locate the `Servers` project
- right-mouse click
- Open Project

Answer (score 5):

You have been closed server project in eclipse which will come by default after adding tomcat into eclipse. So try to open server project and start Tomcat it will Work..

Steps:

1. Go to project explorer.
2. Double click on server project.

Answer (score 3):

You installed Tomcat v6 within eclipse using the “Add server” wizard and the  “download and install” button.

You tried to start Tomcat and got the following error:

****“Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete”****

How to solve:

1) . Close Eclipse

2) . Copy all files from TOMCAT_6_HOME/conf to WORKSPACE_FOLDER/Servers/Tomcat   v6.0 Server at localhost-config

3) . Start Eclipse

4) . Expand the Servers project, click on the Tomcat 6 project and hit F5

5) . Start Tomcat from Eclipse

6) . Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just after many trying I got the solution for this problem. The problem is when your server is created using your IDE(Eclipse, JBoss or any) that time the server is not getting the configuration file. To resolve this problem you need to copy all the configuration files from the tomcat `conf` directory to your IDE server directory. If I will step out the solution than I can list the steps as-

- Locate your Tomcat installation directory
- Find the conf directory, sometime you will get it into skel directory
- Copy all the files from conf and now change the directory to your IDE workspace
- In Server directory paste all the files in your Tomcat configuration directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Linux-based Eclipse:

Check user and group ownership and permissions to your server directory and subdirectories inside Eclipse. It MUST allow read-write config files by the current Eclipse user. Test it copying config files directly to it and, after that, accessing it through Eclipse text/xml editor.

It's usefull too to check the same for tomcat directory, because Eclipse may be bloked if its owner doesn't have permissions to access that files.

Answer (score 0):

the solution to this problem is :

cd /usr/local/tomcat//conf

chmod 777 *

and it's done

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. This is because it's missing "Servers" folder that contains Tomcat in Project Explorer. I already downloaded and configured my Tomcat, but after I created another new java web project, Server stopped working.

- To solve this problem right click on "Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost
  [Strated,Synchronized]"
- at bottom of your Eclipse.
- click "General"
- click "Switch Location"
- click "Apply"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYvFH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the "Close unrelated projects" button is clicked. A simple and straightforward solution to this issue:

1. Go to the bottom of the Project Explorer tab and there will be a project named "Servers". If it's closed, the icon will have a different color than the projects that are open.
2. Double-click on "Servers". Now the project will be open and this issue will get resolved.